# SpringBoot Mongo config being ignore by application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Having a really annoying issue with my Spring Boot API.

So I have a MySQL db and a MongoDB which I connect to. Everything with the Mysql works fine i.e. the settings from the Application.yaml file but not Mongo. It ignores the Database name and creates its own one called "test". Even if I put in a random host and port it still connects locally. Anyone able to spot what i'm doing wrong?

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /api/v1/
  port: 8080
spring:
  data:
    mongo.database: springboot-rest
    mongo.host: localhost
    mongo.port: 27017
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_social?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    username: test
    password: test



  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: -1
      max-request-size: -1

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

*EDIT* worth noting i also tied this way with no luck either:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongo:
      database: springboot-rest
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_social?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    username: test
    password: test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mongodb** should be there instead of mongo

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: springboot-rest
```